# Selecting fields in NNJoin plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, distance, select, plugins

I want to know if there is the possibility to choose only the desired fields for each layer that will appear in the output layer on the NNJoin plugin. If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: No.** *Except if you edit the plugins code.*

Alternative: If you are using QGIS 3.8 or above, you can use [Join Attributes by nearest](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?#join-attributes-by-nearest) from [processing toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html) instead of [NNJoin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/). Here you have the option to choose the fields you want to copy:

[image]